# How can I unset env variable when run npm script?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have some npm scripts. Some of them use env variables. For example (just example):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --watch --env.noSourceMaps",
  },
```

So, for now, when I call `npm start` env.noSourceMaps = true

But, how can I unset that variable when run npm start?

If I run `npm run -- --env.noSourceMaps=false` I got `env.noSourceMaps = [true, 'false']`

If I run `npm run -- --env.noSourceMaps` I got `env.noSourceMaps = [true, true]`

If I run `npm run -- --env.noSourceMaps=` I got `env.noSourceMaps = [true, '']`

But I want env.noSourceMaps = false or undefined

And I do not want to reverse logic (I mean, i don't want to use it as  "start": "webpack --watch" and call it as `npm start` or `npm start -- --env.noSouceMaps` or `"start": "webpack --watch", "start:noMaps": "webpack --watch --env.noSourceMaps"`)

Comment: @RobC it just set the env variable to `"false"`. So, If I'll write `--env.noSourceMaps=true` later the env variable will be `["false", "true"]`

Comment: @RobC I don't need exactly false. `webpack --watch --env.noSourceMaps=false` in package.json logically means  the same as `"start": "webpack --watch"` (in the end of the question I wrote that I don't want that)